# change excel password using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, interop, password-protection

I am working on this project which uses Excel.interop to create worksheets and currently they are password protected.Whats the best way to modify the password using c#? I am new to interop, so not familiar with all the functionalities available.

Currently I use the worksheet.unprotect(oldpassword) to unlock the sheet using old password and then call worksheet.protect(newpassword) to lock it back using new password.But then arises this problem. It works fine for the first time, but after that when it tries to unprotect using oldpw, I get exception. So the old pw is a 1 time use, how do i implement that logic in c#? Also I have like 15 worksheets (all password protected) and so it gets complicated when using counters.

Currently I use a try catch block like this.

```
public static void Unprotect_Worksheet(string Name)

        {
            try
            { 

                //try old pw first, if gets exception, retry using new pw

                string strPassword = oldpassword;
                Excel.Worksheet wsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[Name];

                wsheet.Unprotect(oldpassword);

            }
            catch
            {

                string strPassword = newpassword;
  Excel.Worksheet wsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[Name];

                wsheet.Unprotect(strPassword);


            }
        }
```

This works perfectly fine, but I don't really think a catch block should be used for implementing business logic. is there a better way to solve this?

May be I can return 0 to calling method from inside catch block,  and then call a different method to unprotect worksheet using new password. But that would be code replication. Any expertise???

Comment: Why not just change the password in the same operation which creates the sheet(s)? After that point you can rely on using the new password.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Could you please show a sample code or something.

Comment: You said your application created worksheets: it's your code, so presumably you already know how you're creating those sheets?

Comment: its not my code, i just started working in this firm, the owner of the code passed away. Are you refering to this line? Excel.Worksheet wsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[Name];

Comment: No - all that does is set a reference to an existing sheet named whatever is in the 'Name' variable.

Comment: If you're not that familiar with the code, and your try-catch is working (even if not ideal) then I wouldn't worry about it right now.  Maybe revisit once you've spent more time with the application and have a better idea of how it all fits together.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't do Office interop programming. That being said, I do a lot of other programming, so maybe this will be helpful advice.

First, I give props to Tim Williams in the comments above for suggesting you revisit it later once you're more familiar with the code. It's not wise to rework the logic until you've spent some time with the existing code.

Now: If the call to Worksheet.Unprotect (which is a COM interface) produces an exception when you specify the wrong password, then you're going to have to try/catch the exception. That appears to be the only way to handle the error. So, to answer one question of yours, you need that try/catch block.

Given the code you provided, I might re-work it like this:

```
string strPassword = oldpassword;
Excel.Worksheet wsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[Name];

try { 
  // try the old password first (throws a COM exception if it fails)
  wsheet.Unprotect(oldpassword);
} catch {
  // ideally we should make sure we're only handling an invalid password error here
  try {
    // couldn't unprotect with the old password - try the new password
    strPassword = newpassword;
    wsheet.Unprotect(strPassword);
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    // TODO neither password worked - what do we do now? [insert code here...]
  }
}
```